# разрешить серверу вызывать расширения

Tags: freebsd

Приветствую.Собрал веб сервер на основе FreeBSD и столкнулся с проблемой. Сервер сам не может вызывать расширение такие как php, node, phantomjs (из командной строки админа они работают). Как можно дать серверу возможность их вызова?

Comment: Сегодня мой хрустальный шар какой-то мутный. Почему сервер не может вызвать? Логи, тексты ошибок?

Comment: @arrowd Например php при вызове через shell_exec возвращает "phantomjs: not found". А фантом просто не может открывать .php по каким то причинам.